# How To check if an attribute exists at runtime on a NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

How to check if an attribute exists for a particular entity at runtime. I will implement a property named dateAddStamp, but not all entities have this attribute. This class will serve as a base for other entity's classes... So I want to check at runtime If I can call  [self setPrimitiveValue:xxx forKey:xxx] or not... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
BOOL hasFoo = [[myObject.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"foo"] != nil;
```

Answer (score 10):

in swift

```
 let hasFoo =  myObject.entity.propertiesByName.keys.contains("foo")
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to improve omz's answer, you should also check if the property is an attribute (and not a relationship named @"foo") :

```
    BOOL hasFoo = ( [[myObject.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"foo"] != nil 
&& ([[[myObject.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSAttributeDescription class]]) )
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.2**
Use contains check from array of keys:

```
if managedObject.entity.attributeKeys.contains("yourKey") {
   let value = managedObject.value(forKey: "youreKey") as! ClassName)

}
```

**or use if-let :**

```
if let data = managedObject.value(forKey: "youreKey") {
   let value = data as! ClassName
}
```